# Find Activation arguments of other UWP app

Tags: .net, uwp

I want to find the activation arguments e.g. from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation?view=winrt-19041) of another UWP app that is running from my console program (normal .NET core program). Is this possible?

Comment: The activation arguments are thrown away after activation completes. They are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Is there any way to intercept them then? In the case that the console program was started initially and is watching for UWP processes to launch.

Comment: Do you mean you launch a uwp app from your console app? May I know why do you want to find the activation arguments? Can you show more details about your expected behavior and what you have achieved currently?

Comment: I only want the information so that I can keep track of other apps and launch them with the same parameters if need be.

Comment: Can you show some information about how you launch uwp apps and pass the parameters?

Comment: I do not launch the UWP apps from my console app or anything, but examples of how the UWP apps are started include app started to open a file, app started because it is registered as able to scan barcode etc

Comment: If you want to get the activation arguments of uwp app which will launch and then launch them with the same parameters, currently there is no method can achieve it.

Comment: Ah, I see. How about just the first part then, getting just the activation arguments e.g. for logging purposes. This is especially useful when you can monitor why a UWP app was launched, e.g. UWP App was launched with file <FILE>

Comment: You can not monitor the launch of uwp apps and get the activation arguments.